# A form with an arbitrary number of fields in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am a beginner web developer and just learning Django.

Question: I have a ListView that displays pictures (16-100 or more) on a website page. Each picture has a checkbox. The user can select multiple images and assign them a tag (from input field). How can I make a Django form for this? And how to process it correctly in my ListView?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good way. But I did so.

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if tag := self.request.GET.get('tag'):
        select_tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(tag=tag)[0]
        for key, value in self.request.GET.items():
            if key.isdigit() and value == 'on':
                Image.objects.get(pk=key).tags.add(select_tag.pk)
```

and template

```
     <form action="" class="tm-text-primary" method="GET" id="tag_selector">
          Тег: <input name="tag" type="input">&nbsp;
        </form>
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ image.pk }}" name="{{ image.pk }}" form="tag_selector">
```